# Python yield returns characters instead of string from single-element tuple

Tags: python, yield

I'm using `yield` to process each element of a list. However, if the tuple only has a single string element, `yield` returns the characters of the string, instead of the whole string:

```
self.commands = ("command1")
...
for command in self.commands:
        yield command            # returns 'c' not 'command1'
```

how can i fix this?

Thanks

Comment: That's not a tuple.  What makes you think `self.commands` is a tuple?  What tutorial are you using?

Comment: i thought round-brackets indicated a tuple. was reading diveintopython, but might have mis-read it.

Comment: http://diveintopython.org/getting_to_know_python/tuples.html - "A tuple is defined in the same way as a list, except that the whole set of elements is enclosed in parentheses instead of square brackets. "

Comment: @timmy: parenthesis (round brackets) only indicate a grouped expression, e.g. `(1+2)*3`. You don't need parenthesis around a tuple, e.g. `x = a,b` is equivalent to `x = (a,b)`.

Comment: @timmy: Good start, keep reading and quote the next section, too, please.

Comment: @S.Lott: what do you mean "the next section"?

Comment: @Timmy: the part where it explains how to do a "singleton tuple".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A tuple having only 1 element should be [written with a trailing comma](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-buffer-xrange).

```
self.commands = ("command1",)
```

Comment: ...With the parentheses being optional.

Comment: @timmy: It is a good idea to accept the answer if it helped you. Go ahead and click on the "tick mark" icon next to the answer.

Comment: @manoj, shahjapan - would be great if you guys had a little patience. i can't accept an answer immediately

Answer (score 0):

```
self.commands = ["command1"]
```

You never told the loop that you had a list, so it's treating the string as the sequence.

edit: or you could just fix the tuple, as recommended ... I assumed you'd want to use a list instead of a tuple.